# How to push a fixed div down if content expands

Tags: html, css

I have a footer that has a fixed position at the bottom of the page with a z index of 999999.
My main content container grows in length the more posts by users added and the scroll bar appears if it is larger than the page. If I scroll down the main bottom of the main content div is hidden behind the footer because of the z index. I tried removing it but now it goes on top. Is it possible to push the footer down when the main content expands?

```
#footer {
position:fixed;
z-index:999999;
bottom: 0;
width: 100%;
height: 50px;
margin-top: 25px;
background-color: #333;
}

#main-content {
position: absolute;
overflow: hidden;
z-index: 10;
-moz-border-radius: 8px; /* Firefox */
-webkit-border-radius: 8px; /* Safari, Chrome */
border-radius: 8px; /* CSS3 */
behavior: url('../pie/pie.htc');
border: 5px solid #0f344f;
background: #ffffff;
left: 100px;
top: 195px;
width: 600px;
height: auto;
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Perhaps giving your main content padding at the bottom might solve this

```
#main-content {padding-bottom:50px;}
```

Comment: Dude, right on the fricken money!!! Thanks man, I'll accept it as the answer once it lets me!

Comment: No problem, glad to help - just pay it forward ;)

Comment: @Replico I'm doing the same thing on the top of a page, i used the ´padding-top: 100px´ on my ´body´ tag and even on the next element that shows up after the first ´div´, but i cant seem to keep the page from loading under the fixed ´div´. Any ideas?

Comment: Figured it out... just tried ´margin-top: 100px;´ on the element that followed the fixed ´div´ and it worked